# Pair an input tensor with different (randomly chosen) elements of the output tensor in each epoch

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am looking to train a model with a cycle loss (similar to CycleGAN) on a different x/y paired dataset in each epoch. The aim is that, across many epochs, the model would be trained on many if not all of the admissible pairings of the elements of x with y.

1. E.g., suppose 2 `tf.data` datasets: `x_tf_data` and `y_tf_data`. Each element of `x_tf_data` can be paired with 1 or more elements of `y_tf_data`. E.g., the first element of `x_tf_data` can be paired with the first 10 elements of `y_tf_data`. This is given by a list of vectors denoted `list_vectors` such that `list_vectors[0] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and `list_vectors[i-1]` are the `y_tf_data` elements that can be paired with the i'th element of `x_tf_data`.
2. In each epoch, the x/y pair presented to the model should be (potentially) different. E.g., in each epoch, the first element of `x_tf_data` can be paired with any of the first 10 elements of `y_tf_data`. This can be achieved by randomly selecting 1 element of `list_vectors[i]`, for all `i`, in each epoch.

What may be a scalable solution?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimentation, what worked best was to create set of N tf.data Datasets in which each element of x was paired with a randomly chosen element of y, and then to sequentially concatenate the set of N Datasets to form one humungous Dataset. This Dataset was then saved to file and read into Keras. This achieved two goals. It helped the model converge more quickly because all the data did not change each epoch and it helped to ensure that a sufficient number of pairings were used for each element of x so as to get robust results.